# Trying to host on Railway but get Error: Cannot find module './models/product'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, ejs, railway

Railway error

[image: 1]

I decided to host my website(made on express.js) on railway. But i get Error: Cannot find module './models/product'. Even if it works on localhost

How directory looks

[image: 2]

Why this is happening ? And how can i fix it ?

But this won`t happen on localhost. And no matter how i`ll try to change path to index.js it won`t work.

Comment: Please [do not upload images of code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/984422) when asking a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was when choosing the `PORT` to connect. Railway.com hosting needs an `.env` variable to choose which port to use.
I hadn't written this, so hosting returned an error. This is how it was resolved:

```
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => {
    console.log("On work")
})
```